# Converting wgs84 POINT into Coordinate LON, LAT

Tags: point, wgs84

I have this definition of wgs84 POINT:

```
enforce_geotype_coordinate_wgs  ((geometrytype(coordinate_wgs84) = 'POINT'::text) 
enforce_dims_coordinate_wgs84   (st_ndims(coordinate_wgs84) = 3)    
enforce_srid_coordinate_wgs84   (srid(coordinate_wgs84) = (-1)) "
```

Looks like:

“0101000000315601E572722F40842D615AA089444”

I don’t know the function of PostGIS that transforms this point into GD (Latitude , Longitude) [GPS] coordinate.
Can you help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simple using:

ST_X("coordinate_wgs84") as X,
ST_Y("coordinate_wgs84") as Y.